# Separate thread for saving django models

Tags: database, django, postgresql, thread-safety, gil

I am building an application that uses a remote database - it saves objects of type A **to the database** and reads objects of type B **from the database**.

As [saving models has the potential to block and release the GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631419/python-gil-is-django-save-blocking) and the application doesn't use the saved objects itself, I want to move the call to `.save()` to a separate thread.

I know that Django is generally not thread safe. So my question is - can there be any problem with querying for objects of type B while the other thread saves objects of type A?

Answer (score 2):

This does not actually answer the question, but I think you would be better off setting up a message queue system and use another process to process the messages.

Instead of saving, put the new/modified object in a local storage (a service à la GAE Tasks Queues or Amazon SQS is best but any kind of local storage would do) and process them on the side.

However, basically, you're implementing a database replication scheme (even with threads, your local storage is memory) so may be you should consider actually using full featured replication.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go about it is to offload it to separate process using [ztask](https://github.com/dmgctrl/django-ztask).

```
from django_ztask.decorators import task

@task()
def delayed_save(obj):
    obj.save()

...

your_object.something = "something"
delayed_save.async(your_object)
```