# Can I get SQLITE3 to work in multiple c-threads?

Tags: sqlite

I'm writing a python program which accesses two different SQLITE3 databases in two different python threads.  Am I right in thinking that this will use 2 cores on my machine?

Comment: Are you reading or writing? SQLite only supports one writer at a time, so no matter what you or Python does, if you're trying to improve write speed by multithreading, it won't help.

Comment: even in different databases ?  Does that count for different processes too?

Comment: The lock is per database, and counts for other processes too.

Answer (score 0):

This [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631419/python-gil-is-django-save-blocking) implies that the pysqlite module releases the GIL while calling the C-language sqlite API. So both cores must be used efficiently. What happens when the result sets are processed by Python is another matter, and there can be a slow-down related to the global interpreter lock. In the case of relatively fast SQL queries, using processes instead of threads could be a bit faster. (I did not check the pysqlite source code myself).